# Print every string that is matched by regex in order

Tags: bash, awk, grep

After an hour of searching on the Internet, I still cannot make this simple task work properly:

Filter the following lines

```
strawberries blueberries tastyapplepies are on the desk
apple banana pineapple guava applejuice quite delicious
```

into

```
tastyapplepies
apple pineapple applejuice
```

by finding whether each field contains `apple` and using commands such as `grep` and `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
awk '{c=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/apple/) printf "%s%s",(++c>1?OFS:""),$i; if (c) print ""}' file
```

Try all solutions for input where `apple` appears in the last field of some but not all lines, and a line that doesn't contain `apple`, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
strawberries blueberries tastyapplepies are on the desk
apple banana pineapple guava applejuice quite delicious
here is a line without the target word
here is a line ending in apple

$ awk '{c=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/apple/) printf "%s%s",(++c>1?OFS:""),$i; if (c) print ""}' file
tastyapplepies
apple pineapple applejuice
apple
```

Comment: What's the difference between yours and Vikas'?

Comment: Vikas' is incorrectly (and so uselessly) testing `i==NF`, using unnecssary parens around `printf` args, will produce a trailing blank char at the end of lines where `apple` does not appear as the last field on the line, and will print a blank line for every input line that doesn't contain `apple`. Mine is one of the idiomatic awk solutions (the other being to build up a string in the loop and then print it).

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't mention what it should behaves if the line does not match any, but thanks for making it better to fit in more cases.

Comment: When you ask for a script to print stuff that matches, having it not print anything when it doesn't match is the expected default behavior, you only need to state your requirements if you want something other than that.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/apple/){if(i==NF){printf("%s", $i);} else {printf("%s ",$i);}}}print "";}' <input.txt>
```

Comment: Thanks for making your answer more strictly to the the my question. This output will right piped into another program to make further "decoration", so the trailing space does not matter.

Comment: As well as adding a blank line to the end of every line that contains `apple` but not in the last field, that will print a blank line for every line that doesn't contain `apple`.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -anE'$,=" ";@a=grep/apple/,@F and say@a'
```